# Find the derivative of $f(z)=z^{1+2i}$

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

I'm trying to solve the following problem.

> For $f(z)=z^{1+2i}$, compute $f'(1)$.

Since $z$ is entire, we can simply take the derivative with respect to $z$, giving
$$ f'(z)=\frac{d}{dz}\left[z^{1+2i}\right] =(1+2i)z^{2i}=(1+2i)\exp(2i \ Log(z))$$

$$ \therefore f'(1)=1+2i $$

Where $Log(z)$ is the principal value of $\log(z)$, i.e. $Log(z)=\ln(r)+i\theta$.

My question is regarding the following work. My first attempt at the problem utilized the power rule right off the bat. 
$$ z^c=\exp(c \ Log(z)) \Rightarrow z^{1+2i}=\exp[(1+2i) \ Log(z)] = e^{1+2i}e^{Log(z)} \\ \Rightarrow \frac{d}{dz}[e^{1+2i}e^{Log(z)}]=\frac{e^{1+2i}}{z}$$

$$ \therefore f'(1)=e^{1+2i} $$

Why is it incorrect to apply the power rule at the beginning rather than the end?

Thanks!

=====================

Edit: Algebra errors.... Here's the correct solution using my first attempt. 
$$ z^{1+2i}=\exp[(1+2i) \ Log(z)] = e^{{(Log(z))}^{(1+2i)}} \\ \Rightarrow \frac{d}{dz}[ e^{{(Log(z))}^{(1+2i)}}]=\frac{1+2i}{z} e^{Log(z)^{2i}} $$

$$ \therefore f'(1)=(1+2i) e^{Log(1)^{2i}} = 1+2i $$

Comment: YUP! Good job!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better $z^{1+2i}=\exp[(1+2i) Log(z)] =\left(e^{Log(z)}\right)^{1+2i}$

Leading to the same derivative.

$\dfrac{d}{dz}[\left(e^{Log(z)}\right)^{1+2i}]=\dfrac{(1+2i)\left(e^{Log(z)}\right)^{2i}e^{Log(z)}}{z}$

Comment: Oh shoot, I made an algebra error, didn't I? Whoops.

Comment: It had to be so!! Can you imagine another one perplexity coming from complex numbers? Oh! :)

Comment: @Kosta: Yes, you did. But you have still to be careful. The power rule is restricted for complex numbers!